# CsvSchema and NUMBER

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I created a Java POJO that will be used in CSVMapper.schemaFor:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "mkg_brnd_id", "prnt_brnd_id" })
public class MKG_BRND {
    public int mkg_brnd_id;
    public int prnt_brnd_id;
}
```

However, the CSV values for these fields may be numeric or null.  When it encounters the null value, I receive the error message:

```
Can not construct instance of int from String value 'null': not a valid Integer value
```

I tried to use the @JsonFormat annotation to indicate NUMBER which should allow a numeric or null value:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "mkg_brnd_id", "prnt_brnd_id" })
public class MKG_BRND {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
    public int mkg_brnd_id;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
    public int prnt_brnd_id;
}
```

But there is no joy, I still receive the error message.

I also tried the following:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "mkg_brnd_id", "prnt_brnd_id" })
public class MKG_BRND {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
    public Integer mkg_brnd_id;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
    public Integer prnt_brnd_id;
}
```

Thoughts on how to create a schema that allows a numeric value to have a value of 'null'?

**Update (11/26/2012 @ 11:56 am CST):**

Ended up having to override the getter/setter and manipulate the values myself like this:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "mkg_brnd_id", "prnt_brnd_id" })
public class MKG_BRND {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
    public Integer mkg_brnd_id;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
    public Integer prnt_brnd_id;

public Integer getMkg_brnd_id() {
    return mkg_brnd_id;
}

public void setMkg_brnd_id(String anIntValue) {
    if ((C_NULL_UC.equals(anIntValue)) ||
         (C_NULL_LC.equals(anIntValue))) {
        this.mkg_brnd_id = null;
    }
    else {
        this.mkg_brnd_id = new Integer(aIntValue);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive type and cannot be set to null, no matter what annotation you add to the class.  If these properties truly might be null, you should change them from `int` to `Integer`.

Comment: Yes, I know, the values could have just as well been Integer (and I tried that) and I still get the same error.  The issue seems to be to get the parsing engine to recognize that the value null in a *.csv is a special value rather than the string 'null' and in the case of an Integer, render it as a null.

Comment: If I look at the JavaDoc for CsvSchema.ColumnType, it states that NUMBER: Value should be a number, but literals "null", "true" and "false" are also understood.  I am just struggling to figure out how to get the parser to treat the value as a NUMBER.

Comment: @Dutchman Got it.  I misunderstood. I have no idea then.  Tell you what, update your question with the fact that you tried Integer and it did not work.  Then I'll delete my answer in a few minutes.  You might get more action if your question is unanswered.

Comment: I did finally come up with an working solution of overriding the getter/setter and manipulating it myself.  I would have liked to have tagged the value with annotation of some type and it magically work but such is life.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something to suggest as an RFE at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/issues -- sounds like a good improvement for other users.